# Find questions where I have not accepted an answer – across sites

Tags: support, accepted-answer, search

I can find [questions which I have asked](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/21109/thomas-w?tab=questions). Those where I have not accepted an answer are marked as

> Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?

Is there a way to show all of my questions where I have not accepted an answer across all SE sites? It's sometimes a bit hard to keep track for all my 33 accounts...

Comment: Not really, I fear you'll have to do this on per-site basis. By using the `hasaccepted:no` advanced search operator you can find all your questions without accepted answer, e.g. [on Super User](http://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A105621+hasaccepted%3Ano).

Comment: So, how do we make a feature request for this? Personally, I would like to do this. I would also like to be able to search all of my question titles across all sites as I often can't remember whether I asked on S.O, programmers, Linux, or where